# Is it valid to use React.forwardRef inline inside a component property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-forwardref

Code

```
const TopLabel = ({ innerRef, ...props }) => {
  console.log(innerRef);
  return <Fragment>Top label</Fragment>;
};

export default function TabsWrappedLabel() {
  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Tabs aria-label="wrapped label tabs example">
        <Tab
          value="one"
          component={React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
            <TopLabel {...props} innerRef={ref} />
          ))}
        />
      </Tabs>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

Will this cause issues on re-rendering and instantiating React.forwardRef every-time or is it perfectly ok to use it inline?

How should it be used otherwise?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4qsvy?file=/demo.js)